# Vaadin 24 - SELECT Component With setItemLabelGenerator not Allowing setEmptySelectionAllowed(true)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a simple Select Component that acts a filter and shows a list of Roles (returns the ID of the Role):

```
private final Select<SJRolesQA> toCcBccFilter = new Select<>();
List<SJRolesQA> allRoles = rolesDataService.findAll();
toCcBccFilter.setItems(allRoles);
toCcBccFilter.setItemLabelGenerator(SJRolesQA::getRole);
```

Works great - no issues.

What I want to be able to do - is add an empty value (returns null with display of "ALL") so that the user can UNDO the filter. I tried adding:

```
toCcBccFilter.setEmptySelectionAllowed(true);
toCcBccFilter.setEmptySelectionCaption("ANY");
```

But I'm getting a NullPointer exception. Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.select.Select.updateItem(Select.java:864) ~[vaadin-select-flow-24.1.3.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.select.Select.addEmptySelectionItem(Select.java:965) ~[vaadin-select-flow-24.1.3.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.select.Select.setEmptySelectionAllowed(Select.java:334) ~[vaadin-select-flow-24.1.3.jar:na]
    at edu.sjconfig.views.sjnotifications.SJNotificationsView.setToCcBccSelectValues(SJNotificationsView.java:152) ~[classes/:na]
    at edu.sjconfig.views.sjnotifications.SJNotificationsView.<init>(SJNotificationsView.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HELPFUL answer from @cfrick helped me to simplify the select. I made the select a simple String (rather than an Object from the database) using a new repository method findAllRollNamesOrderByRole().

Now the `select.setEmptySelectionAllowed(true)` and `select.setEmptySelectionCaption("ANY")` worked great. In my change event listener I can then pass the string value to get the ID using a new repository method `getRoleIdByName(roleName)`.

Here's the updated code (just FYI):

```
private void setNewToCcBccSelectValues(Select select) {
        List<String> allRoles = rolesDataService.findAllRollNamesOrderByRole();
        select.setItems(allRoles);
        select.setEmptySelectionAllowed(true);
        select.setEmptySelectionCaption("ANY");
        
        select.addValueChangeListener((HasValue.ValueChangeEvent e) -> {
            resetBtn.setEnabled(true);
            applyFilterBtn.setEnabled(true);
            String roleName = e.getValue().toString();
            Integer roleId = rolesDataService.getRoleIdByName(roleName);
            System.out.println("Selected Role: " + roleName + "; ID: " + roleId);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce this with the example given minus the item label
generator.  Adding a "broken" item label generator gives me a similar
error, but nicer -- the one from Vaadin, that I am not allowed to use
null values here.  So I conclude, the error is in your
`SJRolesQA::getRole` throwing the NPE (and if not you have not provided
the full stacktrace, with the "nice" Vaadin message).

Working minimal example:

```
new Select<Map>().tap{
    setItemLabelGenerator {                 
        it?.keySet()?.toString() ?: "ALL"             
    }             
    setEmptySelectionAllowed(true)             
    setEmptySelectionCaption("ALL")             
    setItems((0..10).collect{                 
        [(it): it]             
    })             
    addValueChangeListener {                 
        Notification.show(it.toString())             
    }         
}
```

Comment: Thank you @cfrick! That suggestion put me on to a solution: I just made the select a String return, and then added a change event and fetched the ID from there.